# OrientDB Can I create a "cluster" with the java API?

Tags: orientdb

Hi my application embedded OrientDB.
I want to create Multi-tenant application système, for my users.

I wonder If  I Can create "cluster" with the java API?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can and is super easy:

```
db.addCluster("yourNewCluster");
```

Comment: thanks Lyca,  how can i have the db object without orientdb-object.jar?